# Why are my .svg files only being compressed when viewing via a private tab?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, svg, gzip

I've configured my .htaccess file to enable gzip compression for .svg files. When I look at the Network tab in dev tools after loading the page with cache disabled, the files have not been received in a compressed format.

However when I do the same in an Incognito tab the compression is working as expected.

Both windows are loading the page without using cache. What could possibly be causing the difference?

If it helps, the page I'm currently testing is [REMOVED].

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Check the "accepted encoding" headers you send in the request to the server. Any differences?

Comment: Both are identical: "gzip, deflate, sdch"

Comment: I have just noticed though there are a lot less response headers in the Incognito request, and that statues code is 304 as opposed to 200 in the regular tab. Could be related?

Comment: Then the incognito tab uses the cache.

Comment: My god that's it, how silly of me. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to [arkascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248114/arkascha) for helping me out here.

I'm am silly and was debugging the compression with cache disabled via web tools. As a result the files I was requesting were being received uncompressed.

By simply disabling cache via dev tools I was able to see the compress working as expected.